# Как правильно сделать этот текст

Tags: вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как правильно такое верстать? градиентом не могу сделать так же

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать мой вариант. С добавлением градиента для текста, так же вы сможете почитать эту [статью](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color) про методы заливки текста.

```css
body {
 background: black;
}

.gradient-all {
  font-size: 2em;
  background: linear-gradient(199deg, #e5e5e5 20%, #464646 70%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-all">Автоматические<br>биокамины</div>
```